# Greasemonkey: how often script check updates with @updateURL

Tags: greasemonkey

On monkey Wiki : "Greasemonkey will check **periodically** for new versions of the script by downloading it". But what does it mean? Once a week? Twice a hour?

Anyone have real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.greasespot.net/2012/02/automatic-script-updates-come-to.html,

> By default updates will be checked for every seven days, and automatically installed when found.

Comment: I plus oned you because I thought you were right but a friend and I did some digging and found out some cool stuff.

Answer (score 5):

While Hellion does point to the original post when auto-update was released in early 2012 this hasn't been true for some time. It isn't documented anywhere so we have to do some digging. You can see [here](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/master/modules/addons4.js#L185) Greasemonkey uses what looks like a built in Firefox mechanism to check and update. It is hard to tell when though. I know from experience that this is in fact a lot less that every 7 days. I have had it happen within an hour. Restarting firefox doesn't seem to trigger it but the shortest I have seen was within an hour. Furthermore if we search `about:config` in Firefox for `update` we can find a particular setting that kinda stands out. `extensions.update.interval;86400`. Obviously this is saying the extensions update interval is set to 86400 second (24 hours). Since Greasemonkey is tying the update process to a firefox update process I would think this is it. I will try changing this setting to see if I am right. Later this weekend when I am done with this userscript I am working on I will let you know what I find out.

Although this question is toward Greasemonkey I will go ahead and say Tampermonkey (Chrome) is much easier to check. Just click on the Tampbermonkey icon > Dashboard then go to settings and you can see check interval is set to 12 hours or whatever you changed it to.

Comment: My buddy Colin helped me on this too. I would mention his SO but I don't know it.

Comment: So are there any news on how to trigger a GM update?

Comment: @Strubbl I never got around to testing it. I do plan to write another userscript soon. I will try to do the testing then. Sorry. If anyone else tests this please let me know what you find out.

Comment: Quick note, the link in your answer points to a file in the Master branch, which has since been updated several times, meaning the line number has changed. Here's a static link to the version of the file you were looking at: https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/2c1eaedc1b814a0861b5573d26c09b90bd4c7c7a/modules/addons4.js#L185