# Including code from a URL into a Greasemonkey script to use it as the script?

Tags: javascript, include, greasemonkey

Say I have a repository on GitHub with 3 files:

1. myGreasemonekyScript.js
2. readme.md
3. license.md

`myGreasemonekyScript.js` stores a Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        facebook
// @namespace   nms
// @include     http://*.example.com/*
// @include     https://*.example.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

// The rest of the script...
```

---

Is there a way just to call it from Greasemonkey so that the **local** Greasemonkey script file will have only an inclusion (an include) of the remote version that sits in GitHub?

Note: The reason I'd like to do that is minimalism, instead having two version localy (the GM script file and a backup in another folder), I would like to center the code editing in one place, without the need to copy changes between each files, each time anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see four options to do this:

### 1. Just install the script from github

**[You will need to tweak the update interval.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618876/607407)**

All you need to do is to enter Raw view on github and greasemonkey will ask you to install the script. I created an [example repository to demonstrate this](https://github.com/Darker/userscript-example).

After the script is installed, go into settings and set the auto updating to `On`:
[image]

Further reading: [How does user script updating work?](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/wiki/FAQ:-How-does-user-script-updating-work%3F)

### 2. Append `<script>` tag

This is pretty obvious solution but unsuitable for production for security reasons. You can just append script tag to the document, linking your script on github.

### 3. `@require` command

This has the flaw that Greasemonkey downloads `@require` dependencies only once, so you'd need to change something (eg. `?random_number`) in URL to force refresh after updating the script.

### 4. [Use my refresher](https://gist.github.com/Darker/14ed6e38641945af09e12a759d25c836)

I once made Node.js script that accepts path to userscript files anywhere on filesystem. It will then search those paths in `process.env.appdata+"\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ap7ptx7o.default\\gm_scripts"` (you might need to alter this path) and every time you modify the refference path (the one in your GitHub repo), it will copy it to your userscripts folder.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on option 1? It seems quite what I need. Specifically, what's `enter Raw view`, and how update fetching is done.

Comment: @sangoko I updated the answer. You will need to tweak auto update settings. It's much easier to do that with tampermonkey in Google chrome.

Comment: Why is number 2 problematic? If I wrote scripts and my browser environment is very minimal by means of extensions. What's problematic?

Comment: @Bernia I didn't say it's problematic, or did I?